# Connecting to the Quickbooks Online SDK from PHP, how do I add a Blue Dot menu?

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have a working PHP app that connects to Quickbooks online, loosely based on [code from Pearce](http://runnable.com/UtEZ4OpSEoFzAACs/quickbooks-oauth-%2B-list-customers-example-for-php-intuit-intuit-partner-platform-and-ipp) (thank you!). I'm using the Intuit PHPv3 SDK (version 2.0.4).

My setup code looks like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js'></script>
<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>
```

and then, in Javascript:

```
intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
    grantUrl: 'http://mywebsite.com/qbo/oauth'
});
```

This works fine, but I would like to add a Blue Dot Menu, which I assume gives the ability to disconnect the session and do other things. To do this, I know that the Javascript should really be saying:

```
intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
    grantUrl: 'http://mywebsite.com/qbo/oauth',
    menuProxy: 'http://mywebsite.com/qbo/blue-dot-menu
});
```

Trouble is, I have no idea what to put in the implementation code for the blue-dot-menu handler, and I've now spent quite a long time trying to figure this out from Intuit's documentation without success.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the Blue Dot menu is actually pretty simple -

Make a HTTP GET request to:

`https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/account/appmenu`

That's OAuth authenticated. Print out the contents of what you get back to the page. Boom, done.

If you want an actual working example, use the open-source DevKit on GitHub - examples are here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Specifically these examples:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3

Which have a working example of the Blue Dot menu all ready to go for you, wrapped up in a nice OOP wrapper:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php

It's this simple:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';

// Display the menu
die($IntuitAnywhere->widgetMenu($the_username, $the_tenant));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following JAVA implementation.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code/blob/master/QuickbooksAPI/Java/Spring%20Application/QuickBooksAPI/src/main/java/com/intuit/controller/support/BluedotController.java

You need to make the following call in the PHP way(using the OAuth and Http libs).

```
final IAPlatformClient pClient = new IAPlatformClient();
                final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                final List<String> menuList = pClient.getAppMenu(WebUtils.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, WebUtils.OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, accesstoken, accessstokensecret);
```

Other things are quite straight forward.

Hope it will be helpful.

Thanks